# What is the opposite of `ngDisabled`?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In AnguarJS, is there a directive that is the opposite of `ngDisabled`? So instead of writing:

```
<input ng-disabled="{expression}">
...
</input>
```

I can write:

```
<input ng-allowed="{expression}">
...
</input>
```

Comment: You could just add an `!` to the expression. AFAIK there is none as there is no `allowed` html attribute for inputs.

Comment: `ng-enabled` is currently in the works. Until then, just negate it. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4240

Comment: @Rob Thanks for sharing the link, that's great to know.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) a `disabled` attribute (but not an `enabled` attribute).  Angular often wraps the underlying HTML elements/attributes for its core directives.  So, I believe this is fall out from that approach.

So, as was mentioned you can negate the expression inside the `ng-disabled` or not include it (which would be the appropriate action in pure HTML).

Answer (score 2):

There is no opposite directive right now, but you could simply delete `ngDisabled` detective from the element you need to enable.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="mySwitch=false">

<p>
<button ng-disabled="!mySwitch">Click Me!</button>
</p>

<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch">Button
</p>

<p>
{{ mySwitch }}
</p>

</div>
```